# Rails - Heroku not loading database configurations as defined in database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have a Rails application deployed on Heroku, it was working fine until we had same databases for development and production. For some reason we had to keep both databases same, so I changed `database.yml` as following:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000
  host: same_as_in_development
  port: 5432
  username: same_as_in_development
  database: same_as_in_development
  password: same_as_in_development
```

Please note that we're not using localhost, it's Postgres URL from AWS.

But Heroku is still loading the old database configurations for production. Have deployed application manually too but no luck. Created new application, deployed code there as well but still it's not saving/loading data from the database as in development. Seems like it's using the database defined in the config vars as `DATABASE_URL`.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku uses `DATABASE_URL` environment variable to configure the database connection.

The naming convention of `DATABASE_URL` variables is as belwo:

```
postgres://<username>:<password>@<host>/<dbname>
```

You can read more about setting external connections to the database from the following Heroku documentation.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#external-connections-ingress

If you read the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) from the beginning it has all the details regarding how Heroku connects to the database and conventions used by Heroku for the same.

Rails [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database) also has some information regarding connecting to the database using `DATABASE_URL`

Comment: But, it doesn't let me edit that URL. How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: It says: 
    Cannot overwrite attachment values DATABASE_URL.

Comment: Can you try removing the current database first from the app. (Ref: https://pasteboard.co/Ho3byOE.png). Then try setting the variable using `heroku config:set DATABASE_URL="postgresql://username:password@IP_OR_HOSTNAME:PORT"`